# Loading a local image directly into a UIWebView without HTML?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a local image file into a UIWebView. Is it necessary to create an HTML file and load the image into it or can I directly load the image in a web view?

This is the code I'm using currently to load the image into the web view, but it shows up blank.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePath isDirectory:NO];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIWebView` has a `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` method. Rather than writing HTML with the image in it, you could do something simpler like this

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
[self.webView loadData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/..." textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

the `MIMEType` argument should be changed to whatever MIME type the image is. (e.g. jpeg is `image/jpeg`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It'll also work for me when I download other file types that UIWebView can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to load an image into a `UIWebView`? That seems like a waste to me. That being said, I'd honestly say that the easiest way to do what you're trying to accomplish is to add a `UIImageView` as a subview of that web view.

You could also do this, I think, if you wanted to inject an HTML string referencing an image stored in your bundle:

```
// Given a UIWebView property called webView, and
// an image named "foo.png" in your main bundle.
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *bundlePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundlePath];
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<img src=\"foo.png\" />" baseURL:bundlePathURL]; // Where foo.png is at that path, hopefully.
```

Comment: That code there remains untested, but I think should do the trick. The important bit is that baseURL part of the -loadHTMLString:baseURL: method call. That tells the web view that any relative references in its HTML body should look at that directory.

Comment: An image is only one of the possible options, I'll also be looking to show PDF files too which I believe can be done through a web view.